# smarty - how to change content of variable using ajax in array

Tags: smarty

status: I am passing associative array in smarty for example:

```
Array
 (
  [0] => Array
      (
        [0] => "hello sir how are you?"
        [1] => "great thanks and you?"
        [2] => "bla bla bla bla bla"
      )
  )
```

now when the template loads I print by default the first index/value ("hello sir how are you") but how can I make the content change when user press some buttons (radio buttons / select) without loading the page again? (like in ajax)

How I can tell smarty to show now the content of index[1] or [2]?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the content of the current page without reloading it, you will have to use ajax to send the new parameters to the page, load it in the background and update the visible code with the new one